# FileNotFound on android, after file.mkdirs()

Tags: android

I use the following code to save a bmp image. After trying to save, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myApp/myFileName.PNG: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` exception. Could you please help? Thank you.

```
public void saveIMG(Bitmap bmp){
    String storageDir =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File file = new File(storageDir + "/myApp/", "myFileName" + ".PNG");
    file.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream out;
    try{
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception exception){
        Log.e(coder, "exception while trying to save", exception);
    }
}
```

EDIT: When I use this code

```
public void saveIMG(Bitmap bmp){
    String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File file = new File(storageDir, "myFileName" + ".PNG");
    FileOutputStream out;
    try{
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception exception){
        Log.e(coder, "exception while trying to save", exception);
    }
}
```

I get a missing permissions exception. Trust me, I am sure the permissions are OK in my manifest file.

Comment: You get the FNF exception because you try to write a directory named "myFileName.PNG". The system has no information whether */storage/emulated/0/myApp/myFileName.PNG* should be a file or a directory as it doesn't care about the extension, so the `.mkdirs()` method creates a directory called *myFileName.PNG*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you got the FNF exception because you tried to write a directory named *myFileName.PNG* (which is not a file).
Basically, the system has no information whether */storage/emulated/0/myApp/myFileName.PNG* should be a file or a directory as it doesn't care about the extension, so the `.mkdirs()` method creates a directory called *myFileName.PNG*.

Your fixed code:

```
public void saveIMG(Bitmap bmp) {
    String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File parentDir = new File(storageDir + "/myApp/"); // this is the new line
    File file = new File(parentDir, "myFileName" + ".PNG");
    parentDir.mkdirs(); // calling mkdirs on parentDir instead of on file
    FileOutputStream out;
    try{
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception exception){
        Log.e(coder, "exception while trying to save", exception);
    }
}
```

> Note that you have to delete the existing *myFileName.PNG* directory before executing this code!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
String filename = storageDir + "/myApp/" + "myFileName" + ".PNG";
new File(filename .substring(0,filename.lastIndexOf("/"))).mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second snippet gives you an exception about missing permission but you have declared `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest then it might be casing issue, see [open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) from IoBridge.java in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387071/open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-from-iobridge-java-in-asynctask/34387100#34387100).

Comment: it is not in capital letters